GCP Cloud Function worker timeout
I have a Google Cloud Function, 1st gen, for which I've set the Timeout value to 540 seconds (9 minutes), the maximum allowed for a 1st gen function. This is a python function that executes a Dataform workflow, then polls the execution every 5 seconds for the execution's status.
Starting two days ago, the function has been crashing at 300000ms (5 minutes) with the following exception:
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site- 
packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 135, in handle
self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site- 
packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 178, in handle_request
respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)

and
[1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:13)

I'm not sure where to begin figuring out the issue, and I've been searching Google and here for "GCP Cloud Function gunicorn worker timeout", but that's only returning results for processes that explicitly use gunicorn. Again, the timeout value for this function is well above the time that this error is occurring.

Can you share the logs, also have a look at this link1 & link2

The error is coming from the Python Gunicorn app running inside a cloud function. You can adjust the timeout in the cloud function code. Without seeing the cloud function entry point code, I have no idea where to adjust this. The Gunicorn timeout might be due to another reason: waiting for some event. This timeout happens before the cloud function execution timeout. See cloud run- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60537977/critical-worker-timeout-in-logs-when-running-hello-cloud-run-with-python-f or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855197/gunicorn-how-to-resolve-worker-timeout
